# How do I run several .sql scripts from one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server Management Studio, I want to execute a number of SQL scripts (saved queries) one after the other. This is simply to make it easier to run each. I could take each script and combine them all into one massive script and simply execute the lot, however I want it to all be separate so I can easily and simply run each bit by bit.

For example, something like this:

```
EXEC ('CreateTable1.sql')
EXEC ('CreateTable2.sql')
EXEC ('CreateSP1.sql')
EXEC ('CreateSP2.sql')
EXEC ('SetupTestData.sql')
```

And that way I can run each line individually and keep everything separate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you like you can run then from the command line using [SQLCMD](http://www.sqlcmd.org/) -i, and put the commands in to a batch script. then you can call this from SQL management studio using exec xp_cmdshell. Actually you can be brave and run a FOR command under an xp_cmdshell and do the lot in one line. Or perhaps just run xp_cmdshell on them one by one

Or you can take the approach [redgate](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) approach and [read the files into variables](http://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/ufsReadFileAsString.txt) and then call exec on them. This last approach is serious overkill if all you want to do is exec a few scripts in my opinion.